# Nuget BasePath option is 'unknown'

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2015, nuget, post-build-event

I'm trying to add a NuGet generation process as an AfterBuild event in a C# project using the following code in the project file:

```
 <Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <Message Text="**** Starting after-build process= ****" />
    <Exec Command="nuget.exe update -self" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)bin\release\$(ProjectName).dll" DestinationFolder="$(SolutionDir)Nuget\$(ProjectName)\lib\Net45" />
    <Delete Files="$(SolutionDir)Nuget\*.nupkg" />
    <Exec Command="nuget.exe pack $(ProjectName).nuspec -Properties &quot;Configuration=Release&quot; -BasePath=&quot;$(SolutionDir)Nuget\$(ProjectName)&quot; -OutputDirectory=&quot;$(SolutionDir)Nuget&quot;"  />
    <Message Text="**** After-build process completed ****" />
  </Target>
```

but I'm getting an message in the build output pane:

```
Unknown option: '-BasePath="<the path shown in here>"
```

I'm using NuGet.exe version 3.3.0 and I'm referencing https://docs.nuget.org/consume/command-line-reference#pack-command as my 'how to use' info.

To see if Visual Studio 2015 was affecting things, I had a go at copying the executed command from the build output pane, complete with the correct paths inserted, and executing it in the VS command prompt. This failed with the same remark, so it appears to be a NuGet issue.

Answer (score 0):

I know that it is super late, but the issue seems to be that you're using `-BasePath=` as parameter, where it should say just `-BasePath`  (mind the blank space which replaced your '=' character).
Parameters are not variables and are "assigned" without an equals sign - just put the value behind the blank space following the parameter name, like this:

```
-BasePath &quot;$(SolutionDir)Nuget\$(ProjectName)&quot;
```

By the way, a similar problem will arise if you're trying to use NuGet.exe with parameters within a (powershell) script.
[See Samuel Lais excellent article about parameters in scripts.](https://slai.github.io/posts/powershell-and-external-commands-done-right/)